# Is Objective C Apple specific?

Tags: objective-c

Is Objective C an Apple language or can you run Objective C on other platforms like linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C is not an OS X/iOS specific language, eg. the GCC has its own, non Apple, ObjC runtime that also works on Linux (not sure about LLVM, but I guess they have their own runtime too).

However, the complete library (Cocoa, UIkit, etc) are Apple only. You will have to write your own NSObject and all subclasses if you want to use them (or use the GNUStep library for this).

Comment: OK so anything is that NS means its part of Cocoa?  NSNumber NSString etc?

Comment: "NS" --> "Next Step", the company that Steve Jobs founded after leaving Apple the first time.  It was a very progressive, innovative place.

Comment: That's not correct you can use many NS-Objects in the GNUStep environment

Comment: While this is true, I already mentioned it in the first post. Nevertheless, the fact is that NS refers to NeXTSTEP like duffymo mentioned. GNUStep was born out of NeXTSEP after Steve Jobs switched back to Apple and forked NeXTSTEP to the very first OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it on Linux using [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) as the compiler. By the way you will not be able to use a full [Cocoa environment](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Cocoa) as a framework. Have a look at this [compatibility list](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ApplicationKitCompatibility) of AppKit

Answer (score 0):

While it's that the language can be compiled and run on multiple other platforms (as others have said), in practice it's almost exclusively used for Mac OS X and iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/).